# How can I create two different Node.js modules in the same directory?

Tags: node.js

How can I create two different Node.js modules in the same directory? Can someone demonstrate how to do this? Maybe it's easier than I think.

Comment: what is the code you would like to be able to write in order to access the modules from your app?

Comment: let's say in another directory I had a node program that did "var module_x = require('module_x');" and "var y = require('module_y');" and module_x and module_y are in the same directory.

Comment: what is the problem you are having the requires them to be in the same folder? Perhaps there is a better solution

Comment: this is an academic exercise. is there an academia flag? waiting for it...

Answer (score 2):

So technically you can put commonjs modules directly under your `node_modules` directory as individual files:

```
node_modules/module_x.js
node_modules/module_y.js
main.js // --> does var x = require('module_x');
```

With relative require paths, those can also just exist in the same directory:

```
my_app/module_x.js
my_app/module_y.js
my_app/main.js // --> does var x = require('./module_x');
```

However, to publish these via npm, they need their own directory and `package.json` file.